# Fetch the first element of an array which is inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to fetch the first element of an array which is inside another array.
My array is:-

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg 
    ) 
)
```

I want to get:-

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg 
)
```

only from it.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: its fixed array or dynamically generated

Comment: try `$array[1][0]`

Comment: use current function to get the first element of a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php
$arr=array( 0 => array ( 0 => "5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg" ) ,1 => array ( 0 => "5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg" ) );
// print_r($arr);
echo $arr[1][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try with current function,Return the current element in an array

```
$value = current(current($array));
```

reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your array is :

```
$arr = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg 
) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [0] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg 
)
```

)

Then do :

```
$result_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $result_arr[] = $value[0]; 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_arr);
die;
```

you will get :

```
Array ( 
[0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg,
[1] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = Array ( 
    0 => Array ( 
        0 => '5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg'
    ),
    1 => Array ( 
        0 => '5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg' 
    ) 
);


foreach($array as $val)
{

   echo  $val[0];

} 

//OR

echo $array[0][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to find a variable in an array. To do this you may try `array_column()`. It might work.